# Effect of oxidation aluminium reflectivity

Tags: metal, metallurgy

Aluminium is a fairly good reflector, but oxidation will reduce it's optical reflective properties.

Aluminium is used for reflectors either being deposited on a substrate, or polished and protected by a protective layer to avoid oxidation.

How will the oxide layer of a several year exposed polished aluminium (indoor) will impact the reflectivity.

Will it be considerable or minimal ?

Comment: Likely drastic. Telescope mirrors are made with a protective layer of SiO2.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik I haven't been able to find any sort of data of reflectivity of anodized aluminium unfortunately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The lifetime of aluminum [depends on the environment](https://www.constructionspecifier.com/selecting-aluminum-finishes-for-coastal-areas/). If it's near an ocean, where air is humid and often contains salt particles, it may become pitted or look a milk white, rather than shiny, in just months. [Anodizing](http://www.docsmachine.com/tech/anod.html) can protect it for years, though.

Because the surface of anodized aluminum is porous (until sealed), it may have a somewhat more or less matte finish depending on treatment. [Bright dip anodizing](https://www.finishing.com/92/76.shtml), depending on the aluminum alloy, offers a more shiny finish.

The [Alzak process](https://patents.google.com/patent/US3401258A/en) is used for lighting reflectors, and there is [information on its specular reflectivity](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7249692/).

[image: Alzak anodized mirror, http://www.miramarmetalprocessing.com/bright-dip-anodizing/alzak-reflector/]